# Error thrown when I'm trying to load log4net assembly

Tags: log4net

I'm try to build project that use LinqToExcel library. Additionally, I'm use log4net to write logs.

My problem started when I'm tryomg to run this lines of code:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(ExcelPath);
return (from r in excel.Worksheet<RowDetails>(company.Name)
        select r).Count();
```

This line thrown exception:

> ERROR MyProj.Program Main:System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: 'log4net,
>   Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'

It's important to note that I'm successful to use log4net before this line.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lots!

Comment: It appears as if you're loading different versions of the log4net assembly. Could it be that you have several log4net.dll in your file system, and the wrong one gets picked up to be loaded?

Comment: I have this same problem; the signature matches in my deployment project, the dll is deployed in the same directory as my assembly, but I get this error.  The first part anyways.

Comment: 1.2.11+ comes in two flavors, "old key" and "new key" you appear to need the New key flavor...

Answer (score 8):

As marc_s pointed out, this problem usually appears when trying to load different versions of the same assembly. Make sure, that your project uses the same assembly version as the LinqToExcel library, which is also dependent on log4net. Also any other libraries should use the same assembly version. To solve the issue, you can also try to use assembly redirect in your app.config like so:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.10.0" newVersion="1.2.11.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 6):

try to install it using nuget

```
Install-Package log4net -Version 2.0.0
```

Version 2.0.0 is for log4net 1.2.11

Answer (score 1):

I'm having similar problem. I think that the problem is in LinqtoExcel referencing Log4Net version 1.2.11, and you have referenced Log4Net sepratly and you get latest 1.2.13 version. In build output you'll end up with 1.2.13, and when LintoExcel calls Log4Net it expects 1.2.11 and error ocures.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after upgrading log4net through NuGet, only to find that the newer version was signed with a different key.

You can grab the 'oldkey' version from [the apache log4net site](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi) and then it worked for me.